# 301 Redirection from folder to url

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I want to 301 redirection http://example.com/imaages/documents/* to http://example.com/imaages/documents.html

Unforgettably tried many combinations nothing is working

Tried all bellow links

http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/
gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Its Lamp Stack

Comment: Have you tried using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess file in the imaages directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^documents/(.*)$ documents.html
```

or this .htaccess file in the root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^imaages/documents/.*$ imaages/documents.html
```